# Azure node.js not receiving POST requests

Tags: node.js, azure, iis, web-config

I have an app that works locally but when I deploy it to azure POST requests receive a 404 response. Various answers suggest that I need to edit my web.config but I don't see what needs to be changed.

If it's relevant: My POSTs are to a path called /receive on the server, which should be handled by server.js

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your Node.js application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=290972
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>

    <!--
    <add key="StorageAccountName" value="" />
    <add key="StorageAccountKey" value="" />
    <add key="ServiceBusNamespace" value="" />
    <add key="ServiceBusIssuerName" value="" />
    <add key="ServiceBusIssuerSecretKey" value="" />
    -->
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- mimeMap enables IIS to serve particular file types as specified by fileExtension. -->
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />

    <!-- Web.Debug.config adds attributes to this to enable remote debugging when publishing in Debug configuration. -->
    <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js" />

    <!-- Remote debugging (Azure Website with git deploy): Comment out iisnode above, and uncomment iisnode below. -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js" 
      loggingEnabled="true" 
      devErrorsEnabled="true" 
      nodeProcessCommandLine="node.exe &#45;&#45;debug"/>-->

    <!-- indicates that the server.js file is a Node.js application 
    to be handled by the iisnode module -->
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />

      <!-- Remote debugging (Azure Website with git deploy): Uncomment NtvsDebugProxy handler below. 
      Additionally copy Microsoft.NodejsTools.WebRole to 'bin' from the Remote Debug Proxy folder.-->
      <!--<add name="NtvsDebugProxy" path="ntvs-debug-proxy/eee3ec35-9835-494f-a07c-dc2f85619df0" verb="*" resourceType="Unspecified" 
        type="Microsoft.NodejsTools.Debugger.WebSocketProxy, Microsoft.NodejsTools.WebRole"/>-->
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <!-- Remote debugging (Azure Website with git deploy): Uncomment the NtvsDebugProxy rule below. -->
        <!--<rule name="NtvsDebugProxy" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true"> 
          <match url="^ntvs-debug-proxy/.*"/> 
        </rule>-->

        <!-- Don't interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="app" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="iisnode.+" negate="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>

  <!-- Remote debugging (Azure Website with git deploy): uncomment system.web below -->
  <!--<system.web> 
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/> 
    <customErrors mode="Off"/> 
  </system.web>-->
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your `web.config` file in my test node.js application, everything worked fine on my side. It should be any other reason which caused your issue. Could you kindly provide more info about your application, e.g. how you deploy to Azure Web Apps, what's your structure and any key code snippet related to the post functionality. These may help communities to detect the queston.

Meanwhile, you can try to leverage **Log Stream** tool to trace the all the info and stdout of your application while the Azure App is running.

You can login on your Azure Portal, navigate to Azure Apps blade, click **Diagnostics Logs** => Enable **Application Logging (Filesystem)**, and then click **Log stream** to open the tool.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: It turns out that I had a stale copy of the app running. After publishing and forcing a restart I was able to successfully post. The diagnostics logs were a big help.